# How to add 3 routes with the same dynamic route (React, useParams)

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I need help solve this routing problem in my create-react-app.
I got three components that share the same route ('/games/:gameId/task/:taskNumber/page/:pageNumber).

For the routing, the switch routes work but not the conditional before it. There's no error. I wonder how to fix it.

TaskPage.js

```
 const TaskPage = () => {
  const { gameId, taskNumber, pageNumber } = useParams();

  if (taskNumber === "5" && pageNumber === "3") {
    return (
      <EndGame
        gameId={gameId}
        taskNumber={taskNumber}
        pageNumber={pageNumber}
      />
    );
  }
  switch (pageNumber) {
    case "0":
      return (
        <StartGame
          gameId={gameId}
          taskNumber={taskNumber}
          pageNumber={pageNumber}
        />
      );
    case "1":
      return (
        <StartTask
          gameId={gameId}
          taskNumber={taskNumber}
          pageNumber={pageNumber}
        />
      );

    case "2":
      return (
        <DuringTask
          gameId={gameId}
          taskNumber={taskNumber}
          pageNumber={pageNumber}
        />
      );

    case "3":
      return (
        <EndTask
          gameId={gameId}
          taskNumber={taskNumber}
          pageNumber={pageNumber}
        />
      );

    default:
      return null;
  }
};
```

Comment: An "index" component that checks the `pageNumber` match parameter and returns the matching page component seems close to ideal to me, though I'd probably use a `switch` statement versus a chain of `if` statements. Is there an issue or something not working?

Comment: I only know how to use ternary operator to render. Since there are three conditionals in this case, I think I was not sure if it's still possible to render. My syntax errors were too messy.

Comment: If the code in the snippet *isn't* what your code looks like can you include an *actual* example of your code? [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Yes, I included in the my edited post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSX doesn't quite work this way when trying to conditionally render UI; `if` statements are not valid *in* JSX. My suggestion was to conditionally return the page component necessary for the `pageNumber` value via a `switch` statement.

```
const TaskPage = () => {
  const { gameId, taskNumber, pageNumber } = useParams();

  switch (pageNumber) {
    case "1":
      return (
        <Tasks
          gameId={gameId}
          taskNumber={taskNumber}
          pageNumber={pageNumber}
        />
      );

    case "2":
      return (
        <StartGame
          gameId={gameId}
          taskNumber={taskNumber}
          pageNumber={pageNumber}
        />
      );

    case "3":
      return (
        <EndGame
          gameId={gameId}
          taskNumber={taskNumber}
          pageNumber={pageNumber}
        />
      );

    default:
      return null;
  }
};
```

Comment: It worked, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: By the way, I'm trying to add another conditional statement before Switch with 2 parameters but it didn't work and it didn't give me any errors. Could you give me some feedback?

Comment: @coderonpointe Do you have this code in a repo or running codesandbox? I could take a look.

Comment: I managed to fix it. So I actually moved the if statement into another component so I can do conditional rendering. Thanks again for your help:)